# Finding Cheapest Flights

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Link to view-only sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nYjjPdGJtg_w37llcuxb9j5GUns7Zk1z5cifG8e0jMM/edit)Looking to find the cheapest flight plan between two points. There’s additional information on the sheet.
Available flights are of the form:

| From | To | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Airport1 | Airport2 | 100$ |
| Airport2 | Airport3 | 500$ |

Sample data with an intended output can be found on the sheet.

Comment: Don't post essential details elsewhere - include the details in your question. Please take the [tour] you were offered when you posted, and see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(SORTN(QUERY(SORT(A2:C6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1), 
 "where Col1<Col2", ), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), 
 "where Col1 >="&F1&" and Col2 <="&F2, )
```

[image]

Comment: How would this change if they were arbitrary strings, like airport names?

Comment: @RogueAstral that would be tricky but I guess you would need to assign a numeric value to each airport representing the distance from the origin as radial sectors and then just cross-VLOOKUP it from such a table.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I've added some more data to the linked sheet.

Comment: @RogueAstral imagine a map like https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuYQT.png where airports in each gradient are +1 so when you start from red that's an origin so its 0, orange 1, yellow 2, etc. table would look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYNtC.png and then the formula would be: `=INDEX(QUERY(SORTN(QUERY(SORT({VLOOKUP(A2:B6, L:M, 2, ), C2:C6}, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1), 
 "where Col1<Col2", ), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), 
 "where Col1 >="&F1&" and Col2 <="&F2, ))`